# Bug with pasting root password to connect via SSH from Ubuntu 20.04 to Alma Linux 9 remote server

Tags: 20.04, password, openssh, paste

**Summarize the problem**

Im running into a strange bug, by pasting the root password into the prompt while connecting via SSH from a Ubuntu 20.04. client to a AlmaLinux 9.2. remote server.

Client: Ubuntu 20.04. LTS
Remote server: AlmaLinux 9.2.

**Steps to reproduce:**

a) Change remote servers root password

b) Reboot remote server

c) Connect from Ubuntu client to remote server by "ssh root@server" and paste the root password into the prompt -> Error message "Permission denied, please try again."

d) Type password manually without pasting the password -> successfully logged in!

e) exit from host

f) Connect again to the same host by "ssh root@server" and paste the root password again into the prompt ->  successfully logged in!

After one time logged in by typing the password manually, Im able to reconnect and paste the password, till the next password change and reboot of the remote server. When the server was rebooted, I have to run again the same process beginning from c).

When I say "paste", I mean pasting into the Ubuntu terminal with "ctrl+shift+v" or right-click -> paste"

**Provide details and any research**
**Solution**:

**Deactivate "bracketed-paste"** (thanks to https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/14129):

1. Create file ~/.inputrc (on client-side Ubuntu) if not already existing and add "set enable-bracketed-paste off"
2. open a new terminal
3. Connect to server by "ssh root@server"
4. Paste root password into the prompt -> logged in successfully!

**BUT!**:
This works even if ~/.inputrc file was created and then deleted afterwards, till the next password change and reboot of remote server.

**Example**:

a) Create file ~/.inputrc (on clientside Ubuntu) and add "set enable-bracketed-paste off"

b) connect to server by pasting root password works

c) exit from host

d) remove ~/.inputrc file

e) connect to server by pasting root password still works - even with a new terminal

If I reboot the remote server I have to recreate the local ~/.inputrc file to be able to connect by SSH using root user and pasting his password.

Any idea what is going on here?